# System.Data.DataRowView in DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-select

I am trying to populate a dropdown using values from a column. Now the problem is: I am not getting the actual values (the country codes like India(+61)) in the dropdown. Instead I am getting "System.Data.DataRowView" (multiple times) in the dropdown.

```
 public void bind()
 {
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
    con.Open();
    string strQuery = "select CountryCode from AUser";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        da.Fill(ds1, "AUser");
    ddlMobile.DataSource = ds1.Tables["AUser"];
    ddlMobile.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

I am calling the bind method on `page_load`. Data type for `CountryCode` is `varchar(50)` & values are like `India(+91)`, `Australia(+61)` etc...

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: Can you plese explain in detail what exactly is your problem.

Comment: I am not getting the actual values (the country codes like India(+61)) in the dropdown. Instead I am getting "System.Data.DataRowView" (multiple times) in the dropdown.

Comment: I'm sure that your problem is that you don't specify wich column in the `DataRowView` display. Show us your aspx code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should set the `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` Properties of the drop down.

```
ddlMobile.DataSource = ds1.Tables["AUser"];
ddlMobile.DataValueField = "CountryCode";
ddlMobile.DataTextField = "CountryName";
ddlMobile.DataBind();
```

Here CountryCode and CountryName must be the column names corresponding to those values in your DataRow

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing what the default implementation of DataRowView.ToString() does. To pick specific fields from within the DataRow to display, do something like this.

```
ddlMobile.DataSource = ds1.Tables["AllUser"];
ddlMobile.DataTextField = "CountryCode"; // This is text displayed
ddlMobile.DataValueField = "CountryCode"; // This is the value returned
ddlMobile.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set the `DataTextField` in the `DropDownList`. It's recommended to set also the `DataValueField`
In your aspx add the `DataTextField` property:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMobile" runat="server" 
                  DataTextField="CountryCode"
                  DataValueField="CountryCode" />
```

You can also set it in the code behind, like the other answers show.

Otherwise the behaviour that you are seeing, is because the DataBound is calling the `ToString()` to display the info, as you don't provided wich data field look for.