# Updating data from combobox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

What i am trying to do is when a user selects a company from a comboBox then clicks the button the different text boxes are supposed to show the different data from the database.

This is what i have but it doesnt seem to work.

Any suggestions?

```
private void Edit_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Companies", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";




        }
    }

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String company = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        String check = @"SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE Name=@name";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(check, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = company;



            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                textBox1.Text = (reader["Name"].ToString());
                textBox2.Text = (reader["PhNo"].ToString());
                textBox3.Text = (reader["Email"].ToString());
                textBox4.Text = (reader["Acc"].ToString());
                textBox5.Text = (reader["Address"].ToString());
                textBox6.Text = (reader["Suburb"].ToString());
                textBox7.Text = (reader["PostCode"].ToString());
                textBox8.Text = (reader["State"].ToString());

            }


        }
    }
```

Update: the output of `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();` is `System.Data.DataRowView` so it seems to not be registering what the selected item is. How do i resolve this?

Comment: What you exactly mean by *it doesnt seem to work.* ?

Comment: What do you get in `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()`?

Comment: I click select and it jsut doesnt update any of the textboxes. i get this as the result of the combobox. `System.Data.DataRowView`

Comment: @MattWilkinson Have you tried to debug the code above ? does `reader.Read()` returns true at least once ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `DataSource` of your combo box is a `DataTable`, then the object in `SelectedItem` is of type [`DataRowView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview(v=vs.110).aspx).

So to get a field, you can cast selected item to `DataRowView` and extract the field value this way:

```
var name = ((DataRowView)comboBox1.SelectedItem)["Name"].ToString();
```

In fact `((DataRowView)comboBox1.SelectedItem)["FieldName"]` is of type `object` and you should cast the field to the desired type.

Comment: Oh i see now, that has helped my issue. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String check = "SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE Name=@name";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=ABCD;Integrated Security=True"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(check, con))
{
  con.Open();
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
  SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

  while (reader.Read())
  {
       textBox1.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
       textBox2.Text = reader["PhNo"].ToString();
       textBox3.Text = reader["Email"].ToString();
       textBox4.Text = reader["Acc"].ToString();
       textBox5.Text = reader["Address"].ToString();
       textBox6.Text = reader["Suburb"].ToString();
       textBox7.Text = reader["PostCode"].ToString();
       textBox8.Text = reader["State"].ToString();

   }
}
```

Make sure your connectionstring is proper. Also Have you checked value of comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() and same is present in db?

If you are populating drop down from database then refer this: [System.Data.DataRowView in DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522025/system-data-datarowview-in-dropdownlist)

Updated:

```
private void ComboBoxBinding()
{

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Name,Id FROM Companies", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapt.Fill(dt);
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;

comboBox1.DataBind();


    }
}
```

You can call this function either in page load or in class constructor.

Comment: The value comes our as `System.Data.DataRowView` Any way to fix this ?

Comment: See the updated code in the question, i have included it there

Comment: @MattWilkinson let's try updated code from my comment. Id & Name should be table colums from your Employee table.

Comment: How do i use `DataValueField`? It wont let me use that, It is saying that the comboBox has no definition for this,.

Comment: that still throws `System.Data.DataRowView` as a result

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below it will work,the thing that you are missing is you are not setting the ValueMember property of your combo box.

Suggestion :
1.Debug your code and make sure that your query is correct and your able to    getting the value right values from data source.
2.Make sure that your columns names in your database table are exactly same as you are setting in your combo box display member and value member

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=\"Student Extended\";Integrated Security=True"))
                {
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand
                    {
                        Connection = connection,
                        CommandText = "SELECT DepartmentId,DepartmentName FROM dbo.TblDepartment"
                    };
                    SqlDataAdapter adpater = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                    DataTable table = new DataTable();
                    adpater.Fill(table);
                    if (txtStdDeptName != null)
                    {
                        txtStdDeptName.DataSource = table;
                        txtStdDeptName.DisplayMember = "DepartmentName";
                        txtStdDeptName.ValueMember = "DepartmentId";
                    }
                }
```

Comment: My Dropdown box has got all the correct entries in it, however when i click the button the selected data does not come up, it simply shows `System.Data.DataRowView`

Comment: you should try the code below it will automatically take the selected value in your drop box                                                                                                         string companyName=comboBox1.Text;